# Every Time showing Select Friday only

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using ajax tool kit calendar extender control

In the calendar, I want to show only Friday i don't want show other days. Any help is much appreciated.

I tried this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkdate(txt) {
        var seldate = document.getElementById("txtDate")
        var selectedDate = new Date(seldate.value);
        var today = new Date();
        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday"
        if (selectedDate != weekday[5]) {
            alert('Select Friday only !');
            var a = document.getElementById("txtDate");
            a.value = " ";
        } else {
            if (selectedDate == weekday[5]) {
                var a = document.getElementById("txtDate");
                a.value = selectedDate;
            }           
        }
    }

</script>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" Enabled="true" runat="server" Width="200px" onchange="checkdate(this);"></asp:TextBox>

<ajaxtK:CalendarExtender ID="calext" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" ></ajaxtK:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the client side element ID of an asp.net element you need to use the [`ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) property like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkdate(txt) {
        var seldate = document.getElementById("<%= txtDate.ClientID %>")
        var selectedDate = new Date(seldate.value);
        var today = new Date();
        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday"
        if (selectedDate.getDay() != weekday[5]) { //add getDay()
            alert('Select Friday only !');
            var a = document.getElementById("<%= txtDate.ClientID %>");
            a.value = " ";
        } else {
            var a = document.getElementById("<%= txtDate.ClientID %>");
            a.value = selectedDate;
        }
    }

</script>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" Enabled="true" runat="server" Width="200px" onchange="checkdate(this);"></asp:TextBox>

<ajaxtK:CalendarExtender ID="calext" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" ></ajaxtK:CalendarExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong identifier of your textbox to get value and
    to get day from a date object you have to call getDay() function ..
    use below function it will work....

```
function checkdate() {
        var seldate = document.getElementById("<%= txtDate.ClientID %>")
        var selectedDate = new Date(seldate.value);
        var today = new Date();
        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday"
        if (weekday[selectedDate.getDay()] != weekday[5]) {
            alert('Select Friday only !');
            var a = document.getElementById("<%= txtDate.ClientID %>");
            a.value = " ";
        } else {

                alert('Great , you have selected Friday!');
                var a = document.getElementById("<%= txtDate.ClientID %>");
                a.value = selectedDate;

        }
    }
```